# What is US equivalence of "diplome du baccalaureat technologique (STL) spécialité chimie de laboratoire et de procédés industriels"?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, undergraduate, france, community-college

If someone who has "diplome du baccalaureat technologique Sciences et technologies de laboratoire (STL) spécialité chimie de laboratoire et de procédés industriels" and wish to study further in the US, can he take admission as Freshman in a 4 year university? Or, can he take admission as sophomore directly? Or, is it equivalent to US Associate of Science degree, so he can take admission to a junior level?

To get admission to a US university, official transcripts are required which is supposed to be in an envelope sealed by the school and directly mailed from the school to the university. But since the French baccalaureat trancripts are in French, it needs a translation. So an official transcript can't be directly mailed as it is in French. In this case, what will be the official transcript? Should I take the original transcript to a translator/notary and send the translation along with the transcripts? But then it won't be in an envelope sealed by the school, will it be considered as official transcripts?

Thanks.

Comment: For foreign-language transcripts submitted to American universities, you generally need to submit both a sealed, official transcript and a separate translation (provided not by you, but by a certified translator—which should be easy to find for French to English).  However, you should contact any university you are applying to, to find out exactly how they want the procedure handled.

Comment: Note that associates degrees seldom transfer seemlessly into bachelor degree programs at US institutions.  Priori academic work is typically evaluated and decisions are made about how much is relevant to the bachelor's degree program- often times most of the previous work is deemed to be of no value.

Comment: Ask (politely, by email) the French embassy in United States. https://fr.franceintheus.org/ and more specifically https://fr.franceintheus.org/spip.php?article10

Answer (score 1):

This diploma is a high school diploma with a focus on chemistry and industrial processes. As a "technological" baccalauréat it is designed for people who would like to continue with short-length studies (such as a trade school or something similar).

It is not a university diploma. Do not be confused by the name: it is not related to a "bachelor", which would be closer to what is called a "licence" in France. I don't believe a US university would let you skip the first year with just that diploma. French universities wouldn't, that's for sure. In fact, it's not even guaranteed that you could get easily admitted into a French university with this diploma: students with a "general" baccalauréat would have a clear advantage.

Comment: I am not sure about "It is not a university diploma". I got my "baccalaureat serie C" in 1977, and at that time it was officially a university diploma (the very first degree). Things have changed a lot since then. BTW, my official business card from [CEA/LIST](http://www-list.cea.fr/) states "PhD", but [I am](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/cv-Basile-Starynkevitch.pdf) just a "docteur de l'Université". AFAIK, the OP could be admitted to French universities but is not sure to, and is not sure to succeed.